# Running a QT-GUI program on Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, cmake, ubuntu-server, xserver, cmake-gui

I want to run cmake ( A build tool) which has a QT-GUI on my Ubuntu Server VM. I am currently getting the following error:

> cmake-gui: cannot connect to X server

I would really appreciate any help or guidance on what to do to get it going. 
 I believe that the server edition misses on GUI front for the Ubuntu, but is there any way I can the application working. Running a full-fledged Ubuntu VM is heavy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use cmake-gui but cmake

Comment: I ended up installing xfce over the installation. I am new to building tools in this fashion; apathies of a Java developer and am also restricted by the installation instructions. But learning to build from scratch is on my list now for sure. Besides I ran into some other dependency issues while installing VTK. Thanks for the help.